# Staging with Woocommerce and Siteground

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stage

I have a problem. I need to do some updates for a client and the website use Woocommerce, the hosting platform is Siteground. Someone told me that I need to use stages for updates/ development. But I don't know how to manage the situation because I have an example..

I'm making the stage using the Siteground tools, and now I have a copy of the entire shop. I'm working on updates for 5 days for example. After this 5 days, everything looks great and I want to do "Push to live" but surprise, in this time the production got another 50 orders. What can I do to not override this orders, new users, etc.

I know that I can use the the Advanced Push and to check the tables that I want to update, but we all know how wordpress works, that all the things are actually stored in wp_posts. How to deal with that?

A strange thing is that I've made the stage and right after I've checked if are some updates to do using Advanced Push and got to do update for this tables

```
wp_termmeta
wp_redirection_logs
wp_posts
wp_redirection_404
wp_term_relationships
wp_terms
wp_commentmeta
wp_options
wp_comments
wp_users
wp_redirection_items
wp_term_taxonomy
wp_usermeta
wpk_postmeta
```

Comment: As a new user, welcome. StackOverFlow is coding oriented, so this is not a question to ask here. Now as you may know, Siteground have one of the best support open at anytime with real skilled people regarding WP (and WC). So they will really help you for that, much more faster and in an efficient way.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thanks for your response. I've tried to talk with them but I was not satisfied by their support

Comment: I'm here to find out any other solution..not just siteground

Answer (score 0):

The approach to take will purely depend on what updates were made to the site. If purely plugins/themes were updated you can copy over the files from the staging site to the live site.

However if a more in-depth change was made to the site such as content, structure, etc then an approach, using a plugin, similar to in the link below can be taken:

https://wp-staging.com/migrate-wordpress-staging-site-to-production-site/